# Issues in setting up cURL library linked with code::blocks GNU GCC Compiler

Tags: c++, c++11, curl, codeblocks, libcurl

I know it's a pretty childish question to ask and questions regarding this topic have been asked before. But being a beginner I just could not figure out why the compiler is unable to link the  header file with the program.
Firstly I tried to copy both the header files and the library files in their respective mingw folders. But using both

```
    #include <curl/curl.h>
```

and

```
    #include <curl.h>
```

didn't work.

Then I tried to copy the folder 'curl' (containing all the header files) into the same folder where my program existed.
but again trying

```
     #include <curl/curl.h>
```

or

```
     #include "curl/curl.h"
```

didn't work. I'm running c++11. Also I have downloaded the latest version of win32 from cURL's website and even tried multiple versions of it, but they didn't work either.

Yet more surprising is that curl is running on the command line, though it always give error while resolving host while I try to send an email through gmail.

A basic step by step guide would be quite beneficial to help me setup curl library in my compiler. Please do keep in mind that I am a beginner and that's my first ever question on stackoverflow.

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Whe n you says "didn't work" I assume you have compilation errors. (It would be great if you specify that). In that case I suggest you to check the `INCLUDE` environmental variable, or the corresponding option in Code::Blocks configuration.

Comment: I don't think so, If I would have compilation errors then I think the program must not proceed by the #include line. But it did. All it gave error when I try to use a curl command or function and it gives an error of not 'declared in this scope'

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverlow. "The compiler is unable to link the header file with the program". Header files
do not get linked; libraries get linked, and they are linked by the linker,
not the compiler. You need to get a basic understanding of compiling
and linking with GCC. It is beyond the scope of Stackoverflow to teach you this.
Here is [a fairly sound beginner's tutorial](https://www3.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/cpp/gcc_make.html)

Comment: Thanks @MikeKinghan !

Comment: I don't get it why you download win32 files when you're compiling for GCC. Furthermore curl.h is used at compile time but you still have to add curl library to your project to link it with your application.